# Не могу определить используемый AppAssets Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Взял на поддержку проект на Yii2. В нем в папке ***assets*** лежит около 10 файлов. Я не могу понять какой именно используется по умолчанию. Подскажите, где определяется дефолтный AppAssets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если у вас `advanced` зайдите в

> `fontend|backend/web/views/layouts/main.php`

В случаи basic
`config/main.php`

> `main.php` - `default layout`(для отображение header'a footer'a) для
>   всех страниц в нем подключается стили.

frontend или backend/config/main.php

Вот так он подключается в `/web/views/layouts/main.php`

```
 <?php
    use backend\assets\AppAsset;        
    AppAsset::register($this);// $this - представляет собой объект представления
   ...
```

его можно найти в файле конфига

```
[
     ...
     'layout' => 'main',
     'components' => [
     ...
     ]
]
```

Так как вы говорите у вас много Файлов файлов для регистрации стилей мы можете воспрользоватся глобальным поиском (обычно это `CTRL+SHIFT+F`) по проекту с помощью IDE или блокнота(e.g. notepad++) и найти вам необходимыйс тиль

> больше информации можно найти здесь: [yiiframework.com docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-assets)

Если что-то у вас остались впоросы - опишите более подробно вопрос.
Указав какое приложение вы используете basic / advanced...

Answer (score 0):

Думаю дефолтовый определяется в

> web/layous/main.php